# Full screen Iframe background video

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive

Trying to achieve a hero background video in a sense. HTML5 video isn't really an option as we're trying to ensure ease-of-use for the client.

The Iframe has to scale and fill the entire a devices entire viewport on any dimensions (I.e 100vw/100vh). The best solution I've found is setting the height/width to 300% or so just so it fills the viewport as it scales. Obviously the downside is that portions of the video get cut out which we don't really want.

Another constraint is that the solution has to be applicable to both vimeo videos & youtube, from what i'm finding these seem to scale differently somewhat.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: *Why* is HTML5 not an option?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an HTML5 Solution:

```css
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Code from : http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

YouTube Video:

```css
.video-background {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#vidtop-content {
    top: 0;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
    <div class="video-foreground">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W0LHTWG-UmQ?
controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&autoplay=1&amp;loop=1
&amp;playlist=W0LHTWG-UmQ" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code from: 
http://thenewcode.com/500/Use-YouTube-Videos-as-Fullscreen-Web-Page-Backgrounds

Codepen :  https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd